# How to open equivalent array number on another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, var

*First of all, I am sorry for this title. Maybe it's not the best to explain my problem. Also, I tried going through suggested posts, but I could not exactly understand them.*

I am trying to have the following.

An array with elements from the DOM, that gives:

**var boxes = ["box1", "box2", "box3"]**

And also an array with a popup, with display:none

**var popups = ["pop1", "pop2", "pop3"]**

I want to, when clicking on the boxes[i], to open the popups[i].

So my question here is how do I save that event that gives me the [i] so I can open the exact same [i] on the popups.

Sorry for not using code, but I thought it'd be more complicated. Still, feel free to construct it with this:

```js
var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
var popupss = document.getElementsByClassName("pop");
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.box {
  cursor:pointer;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: #FC543A;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.wrapper2 {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position:fixed;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  z-index:2;
  overflow:auto;
}

.pop {
  margin-top:6em;
  background-color:white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  display:none;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}

.hide {
  display:none;
}

.show {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="box1" class="box">Box1</div>
  <div id="box2" class="box">Box2</div>
  <div id="box3" class="box">Box3</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="pop" id="pop1">
  Pop1!
  </div>
  
  <div class="pop" id="pop2">
  Pop2!
  </div>
  
  <div class="pop" id="pop3">
  Pop3!
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: `Sorry for not using code, but I thought it'd be more complicated` - No need to worry about being complicated, it is even encouraged to include the code you tried so we can see why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Fran totally understand! Thing is I did not want to develop much, because I don't actually know how to start. Still, left this "template" so people can pick on the question quickly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really taking the best approach here. Whenever you find yourself duplicating code, stop and take a breath. There is no need to create 3 pop sections of HTML. You should just have one HTML placeholder for your pop message and keep the possible values for that message in a JavaScript array. This makes the HTML cleaner and eliminates the need for a `.hide` CSS class.

Then, you simply assign each box a click event function that sets the corresponding pop message (from the array) into the pop placeholder.

```js
// Store possible pop messages:
var popMessages = ["Pop1!", "Pop2!", "Pop3!"];

// Get reference to pop placeholder
var pop = document.getElementById("pop");

// Use .querySelectorAll() instead of .getElementsByClassName
// since the latter doesn't perform as well due to returning
// a "live" node list. Also, convert the returned node list
// into a proper array, so that .forEach() can be used on it.
var boxes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".box"));

// Loop over the boxes
boxes.forEach(function(box, index){
  // Set each box to have a click event handling function
  box.addEventListener("click", function(){
    // Use the pop message corresponding to the index of the box being clicked.
    pop.textContent = popMessages[index];
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.box {
  cursor:pointer;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: #FC543A;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.wrapper2 {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position:fixed;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  z-index:2;
  overflow:auto;
}

.show {
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="box1" class="box">Box1</div>
  <div id="box2" class="box">Box2</div>
  <div id="box3" class="box">Box3</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="pop" id="pop"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @scott-marcus!

You are completely right - I do need to decrease the number of code lines. I'm new to all this, but I'll definitely keep this in mind.

Comment: Talking about DRY, putting a function into the loop isn't that efficient, since the parser has to create three iterations of it. Having a named function is better in this case.

Comment: @Mouser That's not quite a DRY issue, it's a memory issue. DRY is about physically typing duplicate code. While your point has merit, it's not impactfull here.

Answer (score 1):

The following (heavily commented) does your trick.
Stack snippet hides the results, so expand to full page.

javascript functions used:

- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)
- [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)
- [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
//select all divs with class box and iterate them
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("div.box"), function(element, index) {
  //we use Array.prototype.map and use call to pass the node list into the map function to iterate

  //assign click handlers
  //when an element is clicked it will fire the function boxHandler. We use bind to pass the index of the element to the function.
  element.addEventListener("click", boxHandler.bind(element, index), true);

  //hide all pops
  document.querySelectorAll("div.pop")[index].classList.add("hide");
});

function boxHandler(index) {
  //select the div based upon the index. 
  var pop = document.querySelectorAll("div.pop")[index];
  if (pop.getAttribute("data-clicked") != 1) {
    //add show to class using classlist.add
    pop.classList.add("show");
    pop.classList.remove("hide");
    pop.setAttribute("data-clicked", 1);
  } else {
    pop.classList.remove("show");
    pop.classList.add("hide");
    pop.setAttribute("data-clicked", 0);
  }

}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #FC543A;
  padding: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.wrapper2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: auto;
}

.pop {
  margin-top: 6em;
  background-color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="box1" class="box">Box1</div>
  <div id="box2" class="box">Box2</div>
  <div id="box3" class="box">Box3</div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper2">
  <div class="pop" id="pop1">
    Pop1!
  </div>

  <div class="pop" id="pop2">
    Pop2!
  </div>

  <div class="pop" id="pop3">
    Pop3!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution uses `.getElementsByClassName()`, which returns a "live" node list and (in most use cases) is not needed and will slow things down. Also, your solution keeps the 3 nearly identical HTML `.pop` sections, which violates the DRY principle.

Comment: Oh, also, your solution doesn't actually work properly as multiple clicks on different boxes will show multiple pop messages simultaneously.

Comment: Working with the HTML the op gave. Sticking closely to his code. However your are right. But I leave it up to him to read your comment and self improve efficiency. Deleted the `getElementsByClassName`, they became obsolete.

Comment: map is unneccessary. Why dont you use forEach??

Comment: Good call @Jonasw

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I've read the provided code differently then you. He wants the boxes to pop up. So I kept the possibility to open multiple pop ups. also the `flex` option in the CSS hinted that way.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')
const popups = document.querySelectorAll('.pop')

const doSthAbPopup = popupIndex => {
  // Replace this with whatever you want to do with the popups
  console.log(popups[popupIndex].textContent)
}

[...boxes].forEach((box, index) => {
  box.addEventListener('click', () => {
    doSthAbPopup(index)
  })
})
```

You may want to add some checks in to ensure that you've the same number of boxes and popups.

`forEach` is good for this as it provides closure over `index`.

Comment: `.forEach()` is not supported on node lists in all browsers and the use of  ES6 here is also possibly not supported everywhere yet. Additionally, since the OP is clearly new to this, providing a solution that uses ES6, arrow functions and unsupported code doesn't make for a good answer.

Comment: @samhh thank you, Sam! Works exactly as intended and I just learned new things here.

Comment: @ScottMarcus New developers aren't going to work against legacy browsers, and new projects aren't (I hope) going to go live supporting legacy browsers without a toolchain in place - assuming such support is necessary at all, which it increasingly isn't. I say this as someone who's only become a JS developer over the last 2-3 years and started out writing legacy code for IE6-8.

Comment: @SamHH  i'm not talking about legacy browsers. .forEach is an array method, not a node list method. Some browsers have decided to implement it on node lists but others have not.  Lastly, there is no way to say what a new developer will or won't be developing against. There will always be legacy browsers and someone will be needing to write code for them. Whether that someone is a new developer not cannot be predicted .

Comment: @ScottMarcus Regards legacy, the likelihood of that is ever-decreasing, thankfully. I don't think it's worth saddling a new developer with that extra mental overhead that will also result in them learning worse code until they reach the point of acquiring a toolchain. Regards `forEach`, I used a spread operator (`[...NodeList]`) to cast to an iterable array. The alternative `Array.from` would also work fine.

Comment: But, you've replaced one potentially non-implemented feature with another, since ES6 isn't implemented across the board yet. And, again, what you think may or may not happen with a new developer really isn't on par with reality. Also, let's be clear that "legacy" may mean different things to different groups. I'm just talking from 20 years of practical experience here. For example, calling `.forEach()` or using the spread operator on even IE 11 doesn't work. So your entire answer won't work in  IE. Is IE 11 "legacy"?

Comment: YES! Edge is Microsoft's browser now, of course IE is legacy. Now, granted, there are many shades of legacy, and supporting IE11 is nothing like supporting IE6, but IE is now a legacy browser all the same. Regardless, it's irrelevant - even if OP will turn out needing to support legacy browsers, by that point they can look into an appropriate toolchain. No need for them to learn objectively worse code in the meantime that they shouldn't even need anyway, supporting legacy or not.